# Will "New Document" menu work with 75+ Content Types?

Tags: 2010, content-type

Got a document library into which we are preparing to add about 75 content types. Current business environment prevents me from subdividing the library into separate parts, and the many templates-as-Content-Types are also needed. I can't control that.

The many content types are meant to be used as templates from which folks would pick via the "New Document" control in the library. I have never added more than a handful of content types to a library before, so I have no idea what that "New Document" control will do with so many possible content types to display. And before I build a test site and create so many content types, I figure asking here first makes sense

Will the "New Document" control effectively function with so many results? Does it somehow group them or just spew a mile-long single column list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this will work just fine.  The drop-down menu for the New Document button will simply scroll.

Comment: I give you +1 for actually answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

End-Users generally try to avoid filling in the data, even the field that are most relevant to them. And we are expecting them to scroll through 75 Content Types and choosing the correct one is simply amazing...Not really :-)

Even though it is possible but think about your audience (generally contributors or owners) with different permissions, limitations of views during filtering with large set of metadata, usability and of course maintenance of large lists. All these pointers will definitely help in making the correct decision.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a page with Nav options to create New Documents based on content types. Let's say you create a custom list which categorises all of these content types. The user can then select the template they want and start a workflow that creates their new doc and gives them a link to it.

Definitely more user friendly than accessing the library and scrolling through so many options.